# Unique value in django model field

Tags: django, unique

I have the following code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()


class Employee(models.Model):
    employee = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    boss = models.ForeignKey(
        "self",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True),
    )
    executive_head = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
        help_text=_("e.g. Chief Executive Officer or Managing Director."),
    )
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["id"]
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(
                fields=["executive_head"],
                name="only_one_executive_head",
                condition=Q(executive_head=True),
            )
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{ self.employee }"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        if self.employee == self.boss:
            self.executive_head = True
        else:
            self.executive_head = False

    def clean(self):
        if Employee.objects.filter(executive_head=True) and 
           self.employee == self.boss:
            raise ValidationError(
                {"executive_head": _("There can only be one executive          
                  head.")
                }
            )
```

What I would like to see is that only one value should be true in the executive_head field. It should not be possible to have more than one executive head.

Using unique_together in the class Meta does not work (in hindsight it should not) because the false values would then not be unique.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using my last suggestion and doing away with the class meta unique_constraint. Amended models.py. See the code. I beg your pardon that I didn't share the "boss" field. Only executive head can be own boss hence clean method works. As a result of the save method, the executive head is automatically updated and the clean method ensures no multiple executive heads.

Answer (score 0):

You can override your save method and update the values before saving.

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    employee = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    executive_head = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
        help_text=_("e.g. Chief Executive Officer or Managing Director."),
    )
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{ self.employee }"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Make sure only one executive_head is set to true
        """
        if self.executive_head:
            Employee.objects.filter(executive_head=True).update(executive_head=False)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Or you can use a partial unique index on the specific field:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    ...
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(
                fields=["executive_head"],
                name='only_one_executive_head',
                condition=Q(executive_head=True)
            )
        ]
```

This will raise an `IntegrityError` as unique_together will do as well. You can catch the exception in your views like this:

```
from django.db import IntegrityError

try:
    Employee.objects.create(
        employee=employee,
        executive_head=True,
        job_title="Job title"
    )
except IntegrityError:
    # handle the IntegrityError with frontend message ...
```

Comment: Thanks, Marco. Both options ensure one executive_head. The second option works well, ensuring the first input is not overwritten to maintain only one executive head but does not tell the user why it is refusing to accept the inputs. The violation error message is not raised because there is no violation. The first method overwrites an earlier executive head input and makes a second input the executive head, which is not what I want. Once an executive head is specified, there should be no other one unless the first one is removed from being the executive head.

Comment: Normally you use a try block to save your objects and get the `IntegrityError` for your use case. So I think the second option is perfectly fine for you. I have extended my answer.

Comment: Thanks again, Marco. Though not a complete newbie, skillwise I am a newbie. My update is above. I restricted the fields in the model to the problem fields. There are 9 more fields. How do I incorporate your new suggestion? The error message in your suggestion I can cope with.

Comment: Isn't there a way of raising a validation_error through the clean method preventing an additional executive head if there already is one?

Comment: Solved using my last suggestion and doing away with the class meta unique_constraint. Amended models.py. See the code

Comment: I was just about to share this as well. Your original question was not clear. One is a DB constraint and the other is a check with a custom message. Please try to focus on one question very specifically. But I am glad you are finding the solution now by implementing both.